# When did "whole entire" enter into English language usage?

Tags: phrases, expressions

As a replacement for whole, entire, complete etc. Why the redundance?
I first heard it in the 1970's.

Comment: tough one to find!

Comment: Welcome, Robert.  This is an amazing question, but if you don't mind, please may you consider expanding this into a proper question? We prefer questions with actual context and research, so they're fully fleshed out. See [How to Ask.](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The language is full of everyday pleonasms, from *advance warning* to *free gift* to *join together* to *temper tantrum*. Why does this one in particular exercise you?

Answer (score 5):

While [*whole*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/whole#etymonline_v_7980) descends from Old English [*hal*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/whole#etymonline_v_7980), the word [*entire*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/entire#etymonline_v_8732) entered English from Latin via Old French in the late 14th c. It wasn’t long after that the two words began to appear together for emphasis:

> As whan yt [the eucharistic host] was [*hool and entere*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED14057/track?counter=2&search_id=446594) — *Pilgrimage of the Life of Man*, ca. 1430.
>
> …let vs notwithstanding be held backe in a short bridle, that god may alwaies haue his *whole entire* authoritie ouer vs, and his worde a full course and libertie: — John Calvin, *Sermons of M. Iohn Caluine, vpon the.X.Commandementes of the Lawe*, John Harmar, trans., 1579. EEBO
>
> indeed i would not much contend with any, that would render the word causally, and so make the verse an *whole entire* proposition in itself, … — Anthony Burgess, *A treatise of original sin*, 1658. EEBO
>
> In Kingdoms therefore of this Quality, the higheſt Governor hath indeed univerſal Dominion, but with Dependency upon that [*whole entire*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?q1=%22whole%20entire%22;id=mdp.35112203450145;view=image;seq=148;start=1;sz=10;page=root;num=136;size=100;orient=0) Body, over the ſeveral Parts whereof he hath Dominion; … — *The tryal of Doctor Henry Sacheverell, before the House of Peers*, Dublin, 1710.

As a rhetorical technique, this is known as [*pleonasm*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm), the use of two or more words with virtually identical meanings: if something is whole, it is entire. The language is full of such expressions: the nature of a gift is that it is freely given, but that does not stop advertisements from offering *free gifts*. A *tuna* is quite obviously a fish, but a tuna salad or sandwich can just as easily be made from *tuna fish*. A number of pleonasms have become standard in legal language: *cease and desist, assault and battery, last will and testament*, etc.

The *whole entire thing* still sounds more emphatic than when either adjective appears alone. While someone eating a whole/entire cake may be a remarkable show of gluttony, eating a whole entire cake likely won’t leave a single crumb.